# Quickblox, send email to new users to validate email address

Tags: email, verification, quickblox

I'm new to quickblox MBaas and I would like to send out an email (to verify e-mail address) to a specific user when he signed up. Is there a standard procedure for this or a way to do this in Quickblox. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a way to do this for API users right now.
The cause of this solution is that it's quite hard sometimes for mobile users to verify an email. Just imagine a situation where user doesn't have a ready for use mail client on his device - then there is no a way to verify an email in this situation.

Other cause is that email verification can complicate your onboarding process.

It's possible to send a greetings email. You can setup it in Admin panel, Users module, Settings tab